# Avoiding select * queries in meta_search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, meta-search

I'm using meta_search gem on a rails 3 site and I'm finding some performance problems with the select * queries generated by meta_search fetching the BLOB fields in the DB schema. I am not willing to migrate the underlying schema to solve this problem. Is there a way to include/exclude certain fields from the search query that get generated by meta_search?

Answer (score 0):

The mechanism to define which fields are returned in a query within Rails Active Record is `.select(...)` which by default is `*`.  Check [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95061/stop-activerecord-from-loading-blob-column) for a way of defining a default scope that includes everything except the one field.

A warning about this, however, is that you'll need to override the default scope when you want to write to the table -- once you use `.select` the fields are read-only.

I use the successor to meta_search called [ransack](https://github.com/ernie/ransack), and given how brilliant its author Ernie Miller is, chances are there's a built in way to do this :-)

Blobs seemed like such a good idea when I first started using them ... but, eh, not so much.