# Set default columns to pull from the database in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, select

I have a `Post` model that has one huge column (`full_html`). So instead of doing a `select "posts".*` or whatever, I want to select every field except `full_html` by default (and only grab it when I actually try accessing the attribute)

My current solution is:

```
Post.select(Post.column_names.map(&:to_sym) - [:full_html]).where(...)
```

but it's pretty gross

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95061/stop-activerecord-from-loading-blob-column) regarding blobs. The last two answers open up a couple of alternatives that you might want to check out. I was going to suggest something similar to the second to the last where you store the full html in a different model and then associate the two together but that may open up other performance issues.